# Why this syntax for link function inside directive is wrong?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have wasted a lot of time to figure out why my directive link function is not working:

In directive code you can write this line for controller:

```
 controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
            }],
```

But you **CAN NOT** write the same for link, like:

```
 link: ['scope', 'element', 'attrs', function(scope, element, attrs) {}]
```

Only this will work:

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because controller is an injectable function, whereas link is not. It's a traditional function where the order of arguments matter, and not their name. It accepts, in order

- the scope of the directive,
- the element of the directive
- the attributes of this element
- the controller
- a transclude function

This is documented: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-